# Cron only runs first part of script

Tags: bash, scripts, backup, cron, rsync

This is the script I use:

```
find /path/backups/ -type f -mtime -2 -printf '%P\n' | rsync -avz --progress --delete --exclude-from=- -e "ssh -p 512" /path/backups/ me@host:/remote/path/server-backups/
```

This is from the log:

```
> Jan 21 15:32:01 servername CRON[14654]: (serveruser) CMD (find /path/backups/ -type f -mtime -2 -printf ')
```

I've tried using `cron.d`, `crontab -e` and `cron.daily`. Both putting the script directly in the `crontab` file as well as calling a `.sh` script file. Any ideas how I would go about solving this?

Comment: This is a bit unclear (at least to me) but based on what you have here a couple of minutes of research I would say it's likely  permissions based if calling the script doesn't work. It's not surprising that a pipe would fail in a cron job as Most implementations of cron do not start a shell with the process in it, and a shell is what would parse out the pipe and run the two processes separately. What IS surprising is that calling a script would fail. You might find [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/23009/reasons-why-crontab-does-not-work) helpful

Comment: `%` is a special character to `cron` (denoting end-of-line - which explains why the logged command is truncated) - try escaping it `. . . -printf '\%P'`. Should have worked OK inside a script though.

Comment: [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/295766/rsync-behavior-in-a-cron-script)                              looks like it's directly related to what you are attempting and might also be useful

Comment: @steeldriver With that method rsync unfortunately tries to sync all files in the directory of /path/backups

Comment: @ElderGeek Thanks for the commet, I'll update if it works :)

Comment: @Ayys well that's a different issue - if you want help, you need to explain exactly what you are trying to achieve

Comment: @steeldriver Alright, I run a game server with a plugin that put hourly server backups in /backups. After 1 day the plugin saves 2 backups/day and deletes the rest. I want to sync this backup directory to a remote server daily (using cron) but only for files older than 2 days so that it doesn't sync files that eventually will be deleted by the end of the day. I use above script to achieve that but it doesn't work with cron.

Comment: Have you tried `-printf '\%P\0'` and then either `rsync -0avz --exclude-from=- . . .` or (equivalently) `rsync -avz --from0 --exclude-from=- . . .`

Comment: @steeldriver Thanks for the help. When I run that I get `find: warning: unrecognized escape `\%p'` and then `rsync: send_files failed to open "/path/serveruser/.viminfo": Permission denied (13)` (even with root). After that it proceeds syncing files in path/serveruser/backup without giving any info of how many files it wants to sync. Really strange...

Comment: Maybe I should look for a new solution to this problem all together, seems more complicated than it should be..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command is getting truncated because `%` has a special meaning in `cron`. From `man 5 crontab`:

```
   The ``sixth'' field (the rest of the line) specifies the command to  be
   run.   The  entire  command  portion  of the line, up to a newline or %
   character, will be executed by /bin/sh or by the shell specified in the
   SHELL  variable of the crontab file.  Percent-signs (%) in the command,
   unless escaped with backslash (\), will be changed into newline charac‐
   ters,  and  all  data  after the first % will be sent to the command as
   standard input. There is no way to split a  single  command  line  onto
   multiple lines, like the shell's trailing "\".
```

which explains why the logged command looks something like:

```
CMD (find /home/steeldriver/forums/tests -type f -mtime +1 -printf ')
```

---

To demonstrate that escaping works, given:

```
$ ls -l tests
total 12
-rw-rw-r-- 1 steeldriver steeldriver  0 Jan 22 14:22 A8eVAmK.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 steeldriver steeldriver 22 Oct 27 22:18 A9E27.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 steeldriver steeldriver 10 Oct 27 22:19 ffn2eG6.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 steeldriver steeldriver 43 Jan 22 14:22 sBHFgkv.txt
```

Then adding the crontab as:

```
* * * * * find /home/steeldriver/forums/tests -type f -mtime +1 -printf '\%P\0' | rsync -0av --exclude-from=- /home/steeldriver/forums/tests/ /home/steeldriver/forums/newtests/ 2>&1 > /home/steeldriver/forums/backup.log
```

(note this uses the null-terminated form `\0`) produces the log file:

```
$ cat backup.log
sending incremental file list
created directory /home/steeldriver/forums/newtests
./
A8eVAmK.txt
sBHFgkv.txt

sent 250 bytes  received 113 bytes  726.00 bytes/sec
total size is 43  speedup is 0.12
```

indicating that the backup ran successfully and copied only the newer files:

```
$ ls -l newtests
total 4
-rw-rw-r-- 1 steeldriver steeldriver  0 Jan 22 14:22 A8eVAmK.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 steeldriver steeldriver 43 Jan 22 14:22 sBHFgkv.txt
```

*Note that you won't be able to test the escaping outside of your crontab - in the terminal, it will result in an error from* `find`.

Comment: Nice catch on the newline (%)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest an alternate approach. Using temporary files can make your life easier and will help you avoid using pipes which can cause issues with cron jobs.

The process here is fairly straightforward. First issue the command

`find ./ -daystart -mtime +2 >myfile`

**Note:**

The above will match files between 2 and 3 days old as it uses integer days.*
Modify as necessary or use -mmin and minutes for more accurate selection.
The matching results will be written to the file myfile which will be`
overwritten every time the command is run.

Next issue the command:
`sed 's|./||' myfile >EXCL_list` to strip off the unneeded prefix. The file  EXCL_list will be`overwritten every time the command is run.

Finally issue the command:

`rsync -Pav --exclude-from=EXCL_list --delete-excluded source/ dest`

**Explanation of rsync switches:**

`-P` same as --partial --progress

`-a` archive mode

`-v` verbose

`--exclude-from=EXCL_list` read exclude patterns from FILE

`--delete-excluded` also delete *excluded files* from dest dirs

for more in depth information and further options see `man rsync`

**Assumptions:**

Commands are run in the source directory that contains the files and folders you want to process.

dest in the rsync command is a mounted destination that you have permission to write to.

Here's hoping this helps.

Sources:

http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/rsync-only-60-day-old-files-580357

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92346/why-does-find-mtime-1-only-return-files-older-than-2-days

https://serverfault.com/questions/279609/what-exactly-will-delete-excluded-do-for-rsync

`man find`

`man rsync`